# Order 18 group containing $C_3\times C_3$ and element $t$ of order 2 such that $txt^{-1}=x^{-1}$ for all $x$ has no faithful complex irred reps

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I had a solution which involves induction from $P=C_3\times C_3$. If $\chi$ is an irred rep of $G$ (our order 18 group), then let $\psi$ be an irred component of the restriction of $\chi$ to $P$. It follows that inducing $\psi$ back up to $G$ gives a rep of $G$ with $\chi$ as a component and having dimension 2 (the index of $P$ in $G$). So every irred rep of $G$ has dimension at most 2. Now given a faithful irred rep of $G$, just choose some simultaneous eigenbasis of $P$. There are 9 possible matrices for an element of $P$. But since this rep is faithful, no non-identity element of $P$ acts as a scalar (then it would commute with $t$). So there are actually only 6 possibilities to distribute among the 8 non-identity elements of $P$, a contradiction.

I believe that there should be a much simpler solution since this appeared on an exam question whose previous parts did not mention induction. We were asked to show that if $Z$ is the center of a group $G$, and we are given an irred rep of $G$, that every element in $Z$ acts by scaling (follows from Schur's Lemma), the dimension is at most $\sqrt{[G:Z]}$ (follows from considering row-orthogonality) and that if the rep is faithful, then $Z$ is cyclic (Schur's).

Then we were asked to prove the above result by "considering the action of $P$ on an irreducible $\mathbb{C}G$-module."

Comment: Your title says "no faithful complex reps", but you seem to be proving "no faithful complex *irreducible* reps".

Comment: Right, of course. Thanks I'll edit that

Comment: As every cyclic subgroup of order $3$ is normal in your group, you could also use that for a group $G$ acting on a set the normalizer of a subgroup $H$ acts of the fixed points of $H$.

Comment: Oh so if any non trivial element of P has 1 as an eval, then all of G would  fix that eigenspace, and so the rep would not be irred. Which means that if we simultaneously diagonalize P, and we pick a,b the generators of the two copies of C_3, they must have the same matrix, or else multiplying them would give a matrix with eigenvalue  1.